# Repeat a certain functionality in a lot of different datas

Tags: haskell

I'm writing a compiler in Haskell, so we have a **lot** *(or at least it seems like a lot for me)* of `data`s and constructors, such as the followings:

```
data DataType
    = Int | Float | Bool | Char | Range | Type
    | String Width
    | Record (Lexeme Identifier) (Seq Field) Width
    | Union  (Lexeme Identifier) (Seq Field) Width
    | Array   (Lexeme DataType) (Lexeme Expression) Width
    | UserDef (Lexeme Identifier)
    | Void | TypeError  -- For compiler use


data Statement
    -- Language
    = StNoop
    | StAssign (Lexeme Access) (Lexeme Expression)
    -- Definitions
    | StDeclaration      (Lexeme Declaration)
    | StDeclarationList  (DeclarationList Expression)
    | StStructDefinition (Lexeme DataType)
    -- Functions
    | StReturn        (Lexeme Expression)
    | StFunctionDef   (Lexeme Declaration) (Seq (Lexeme DataType))
    | StFunctionImp   (Lexeme Identifier)  (Seq (Lexeme Identifier)) StBlock
    | StProcedureCall (Lexeme Identifier)  (Seq (Lexeme Expression))
    -- I/O
    | StRead  (Seq (Lexeme Access))
    | StPrint (Seq (Lexeme Expression))
    -- Conditional
    | StIf   (Lexeme Expression) StBlock StBlock
    | StCase (Lexeme Expression) (Seq (Lexeme When))      StBlock
    -- Loops
    | StLoop     StBlock (Lexeme Expression) StBlock
    | StFor      (Lexeme Identifier) (Lexeme Expression)  StBlock
    | StBreak
    | StContinue
```

And many more. You may have noticed the repeating `Lexeme a` in many of the constructors.

Lexeme is the following `data`

```
type Position = (Int, Int)

data Lexeme a = Lex
    { lexInfo :: a
    , lexPosn :: Position
    }
```

So it works for keeping the information of the `Position` of an element in the *program's file*, for reporting errors and warnings.

#### Is there an easier way to deal with the *keeping the information of the `Position`* problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One could move "up" the `Lexeme` application:

```
type Access = Lexeme Access'
data Access' = ...
type Expression = Lexeme Expression'
data Expression' = ...
-- etc.
data Statement
    -- Language
    = StNoop
    | StAssign Access Expression
    -- Definitions
    | StDeclaration      Declaration
    | StDeclarationList  (DeclarationList Expression')  -- maybe you can also use Expression here?
    | StStructDefinition DataType
    ...
```

In this way you apply `Lexeme` once every type *definition*, instead of once every type *use*.

Answer (score 3):

I'm accustomed to seeing another constructor that can be used optionally to hold lexical information:

```
data Expression = ... all the old Exprs
                | ExprPos Position Expression

data Declaration = ... decls ...
                 | DeclPos Position Declaration
```

Now in your `Statement` and other data types instead of things like:

```
| StFor      (Lexeme Identifier) (Lexeme Expression)  StBlock
```

you have:

```
| StFor      Identifier Expression StBlock
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach

Comment: +1 Yes, once you get past parsing, you don't necessarily need such fine-grained position checking as you have; With this set-up, you can pick and choose when to store pos info.